# How do i install windows without booting the CD?

Tags: installation, windows, dvd

How do i install windows without booting the CD? i ask because when i boot the pc the BIOS skips "press any key to boot from cd or dvd" and my BIOS wont do it if I do it inside from the BIOS ether. But i can use the CD drive inside ubuntu.

Comment: can you be a little more clear?

do you mean you want to boot the windows installation cd on a computer that has ubuntu installed, but the computer wont let the windows cd boot up?

Comment: Is this question related to Ubuntu at all?

Comment: Make sure your CD disk is bootable and is not dammaged. Try pressing F12 while BIOS starts - a boot disk menu can pop-up. Try to configure boot drives sequence in BIOS set-up tool - put the CD/DVD drive above HDD and don't forget to save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to remove the USB drive when the computer restarts after installing windows, or it will boot through the USB drive again, continuously.

Answer (score 1):

Let me first think that you have already installed ubuntu and now you want windows right
then why don't you try the usb 
check this site
http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/create-bootable-windows-7-usb-drive.html

Comment: I have tried to install windows with a USB stick but i always fail because the installation dont complete so it only sow a black screen. And if I don't switch to the hard drive after the install it only begins form start. But do you think i made the USB bootable stick wrong or something like that if that happens?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry the only way to install windows is by using the CD or a bootable flash drive. Maybe you should update your bios?

Have you tried repeatedly pressing F12 or F9 when you turn on your computer (with the CD in) to see if that works? (f12 is what I press on my Acer and f9 is what i press on my Asus)

Edit: With your computer on, put the windows cd in and shutdown the computer. Then turn on your computer and try the F-keys

Comment: I have updated my BIOS, but what do you mean whit having the cd in when i boot?

Comment: You're wrong, using bootable CD or flash drive is not the only way to install Windows. Windows can be also installed by running the installer under working DOS or Windows system. But I doubt Windows installer will do the job if ran under Ubuntu.